# Asterix symbol parsing while using ant libraries

Tags: java, ant

I need to zip files using ant libraries. I couldn't find any examples of using ant not with build scripts but with libraries.

I saw classes from org.apache.tools.zip package but I cant find code that will help me to use asterix symbol while setting files to zip.

So how can I zip files that match some pattern using ant libraries?

Here is an example of scenario: application recieves an string like "/ziptest/*example.txt" so my application has to zip all files which name ends with "example" and extension is txt from ziptest directory.

The point is I need to do it with java code. I wanted to use Ant libraries for this task.

Comment: What do you mean "using ant not with build scripts but with libraries"? Can you give some example? Do you want to create java class which will use ant libraries to zip files?

Comment: Your best bet using ant libraries programmatically is Groovy (http://groovy.codehaus.org/), more details here : http://groovy.codehaus.org/Using+Ant+from+Groovy, http://marxsoftware.blogspot.de/2011/02/antbuilder-groovy-meets-ant.html, http://marxsoftware.blogspot.de/2011/05/executing-ant-build-file-targets-from.html

Comment: My application must zip files. So I need to zip files programmatically from my classes. I downloaded ant binaries and found libraries in lib dir so I wanted to use them to zip files.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create zip files, but you're not already using an Ant build, the Ant zip tasks would be about the last thing I'd want to use.  They're just not meant to be used outside of an Ant build (although as @Rebse points out, with enough coercion, anything is possible).  Take a look at the [ZipOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipOutputStream.html) in Java if you want to programmatically create zip files.